# "Tell someone thanks" or "say thanks to someone"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english

One of my friend came to my place for a cup of tea, i introduced her to my mom. After she left my mom said she is a nice girl. When we met in the college the other day, i told her that my mom liked her very much and in reply she said "tell her thanks"
I really want to know if telling someone thanks is a correct sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"Thanks" is informal/colloquial; the "correct" English is "thank you".

That said, "Tell her thank you" *is* commonly accepted as correct English; it is a shortened form of "Tell her I say thank you" (which is also correct).

Comment: "Say thanks to her" is it also correct?

Comment: Yes, though I'd write it as: 'Say "Thanks" to her.' It's describing a phrase you are requested to say.