# "I want to tell my friend" vs. "I want to tell TO my friend"

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure about the adding of the preposition in the following case:

> "I want to tell my friend that I appreciate her."
>
> "I want to tell **TO** my friend that I apreciate her."

Which one is correct?

Comment: Related: [“say something” vs. “tell something to somebody”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34115/say-something-vs-tell-something-to-somebody) and a possible duplicate of ['Say' and 'Tell' difference!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67738/say-and-tell-difference)

Comment: Also related: [“Tell someone thanks” or “say thanks to someone”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47814/tell-someone-thanks-or-say-thanks-to-someone) and [“Tell to someone” or “tell someone”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49954/tell-to-someone-or-tell-someone) and [Why can't we use “to” after tell?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/why-cant-we-use-to-after-tell) and [Why is “Mary told the cake to be cut by John” ungrammatical?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/why-is-mary-told-the-cake-to-be-cut-by-john-ungrammatical/2830#2830)

Comment: I cast my vote to close this question for lack of research. The OP didn't have to google the answer, only use the search thingy.

Answer (score 19):

The first is correct (although the comma was unnecessary):

> I want to tell my friend that I appreciate her.

The second can be used with a different verb:

> I want to say to my friend that I appreciate her.

Although both verbs are transitive, in the case of **say** the object is *what* you are saying, not *to whom* you say it.

The case of **tell** is more difficult. I can **tell someone** and I can also **tell stories**. For example

> I want to tell stories to my friend.

and even

> I want to tell my friend stories.

---

**Edit:**

The last example is very much like the first example.

> I want to tell my friend ... something.

The penultimate example might be confusing, but starting with the simple

> I want to tell stories

here are some other examples that use prepositions:

> I want to tell stories about the sea.
>
> I want to tell stories from The Arabian Nights.
>
> I want to tell stories after dark.
>
> I want to tell stories on the stage.
>
> I want to tell stories at bedtime.
>
> I want to tell stories to keep them alive.
>
> I want to tell stories between my other activities.
>
> I want to tell stories to my friend.

Comment: Thank you. The comma is a typo. Just now I noticed that I put it unintentionally.

Comment: I think a beginner could find your second-to-last example confusing, because the rest of the answer explains that "tell" is used without "to", and then you write "I want to tell stories **to** my friend". And it's almost identical to the last example, where the "to" is missing. I'd suggest to add something to explain that case.

Comment: @FabioTurati edited.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion. We *tell somebody something*, thus you would say: I want to tell my friend that I appreciate her.